# What's behind Tesla's (attributed) claim that "3-6-9 is the key to the universe"?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> *If you only knew the magnificence of the 3, 6 and 9, then you would have a key to the universe.* — **Nikola Tesla** (attributed)

There are a number of [videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tesla+369) showing some interesting arithmetic patterns regarding digital roots (call it $T(•)$). For instance, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

- $T(2^n)=x_{mod(n,6)}, x=(1,2,4,8,7,5)$
- $T(5^n)=x_{mod(n,6)}, x=(1,5,7,8,4,2)$
- $T(4^n)=x_{mod(n,3)}, x=(1,4,7)$
- $T(7^n)=x_{mod(n,3)}, x=(1,7,4)$
- $T(8^n)=x_{mod(n,2)}, x=(1,8)$

And $\forall n>1$:

- $T(3^n)=T(6^n)=T(9^n)=9$

Also, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

- $T(3(n+1))=x_{mod(n,3)}, x=(3,6,9)$

These sequences are represented in the following diagram by [Randy Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fbyc9JW3vtk):

[image: Randy Powell's Diagram of Tesla sequences]

Another version was drawn by Math teacher [Joey Grether](https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/real-story-behind-tesla-map-multiplication-chart-10889) (who attributed it to Tesla as a hoax, after unsuccessfully trying to divulge it):

[image: Tesla's Map to Multiplication]

So the question is: is there a mathematical structure behind all this, or is it just a simple number game?

Comment: The $T$ function is usually referred to as the digital root

Comment: "is there a mathematical structure behind all this, or is it just a simple number game?" Third possibility: mental illness.

Comment: Thanks, @DreamConspiracy. Updated.

Comment: That would encompass mostly all mathematicians, @Gerry Myerson (if not all). See E.T. Bell's *Men of Mathematics* for a good sample.

Comment: @André, it encompasses hardly any mathematicians, no more than in the general population, but it does describe Tesla, at least in his later years. Bell's book is a good sample of fiction, not to be cited in serious company.

Comment: I don't know what this $3$-$6$-$9$ stuff is about, but the "Map to Multiplication" is really nothing more than a depiction of the integers [*modulo* $12$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), with the geometric patterns being equivalent to (star) polygons with [Schlafli symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schläfli_symbol) $\{12/k\}$. The spirals associated with $11$ and $13$ simply recognize that $11 = -1$ (mod $12$) and $13 = 1$ (mod $12$), so their multiples "obviously" step through the figure in a counter-clockwise or clockwise manner.

Comment: Suppose there is a structure behind it, what exactly is the point? Does that, then, somehow prove it is the "key to the universe," whatever that means. Regardless, its not a math question.

Comment: Also, the diagram drawn 'by Tesla himself' is very obviously inauthentic.

Comment: [citation needed], @Servaes.

Comment: @AndréLevy Not really, just look at it please. The fonts, the date, the lack of aging of the ink compared to the paper, the signature, etc.

Comment: The math question is whether there is anything mathematically interesting behind the claim, @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost. Whether that's "the key to the universe" is indeed beyond Mathematics, and not the question I asked. It wouldn't be the first time, though, a serious Physicist or Mathematician thought he had unravelled something deeper than the Math itself. Leibniz, Euler, Galois and Gödel certainly did.

Comment: @AndréLevy please spare me with the headaches: "unravelled something deeper than math itself." Weird claims, and pointless verbiage is not math, its just that, psuedo-intellectualism and unnecessary spiritualism.

Comment: In that case, I will, @Servaes: [The real story behind the Tesla Map to Multiplication chart](https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/real-story-behind-tesla-map-multiplication-chart-10889), [Hoaxing, The 12x Spiral, and Tesla](http://mobaction.com/hoaxing-the-12x-spiral-and-tesla/)

Comment: Didn't say it was, @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost. Neither did they. "Something deeper than Math" is quite obviously **not** Math. And, again, that's beside the point of this question.

Comment: @AndréLevy I am glad you don't think its math. Now, since you have shown that the chart is definitely not by Tesla, would you also remove the erroneous attribution from your question. Some might actually believe it's Tesla's.

Comment: Done, @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost.

Comment: Btw, @DreamConspiracy's hint has taken me halfway to answering this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic

Comment: @AndréLevy Glad, and upvoted. Cheers!

Comment: "Put on hold" (yawn)... And by people that didn't even bother providing any feedback or seeking clarification (other than @Servaes). Did they bother reading beyond the title? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: @AndréLevy There is a valid and interesting question about digit sums (mod 10?) here, but it is cluttered by (pseudo-scientific/obnoxious new age/I don't know what to call it) nonsense. The part of your question starting from *"There are a number of videos on youtube..."* up to *"These sequences are represented by..."* seems like a fine question, perhaps lacking some own effort (though I haven't checked the youtube link). The title, the quote and the obnoxious GIF (it gives me a headache) distract massively from the mathematical content. Finally, your question at the end is too broad/vague.

Comment: "obnoxious" is not an objective argument, @Servaes. My question, OTOH, is. It could equally be a question about Sudoku solutions or Go moves, illustrated with what may offend your aesthetic taste or not. You've voted to put it on hold for no good reason. Please revert it.

Comment: @AndréLevy I disagree with every part of that comment. I've made my *many* reasons to close the question reasons quite clear, I do not care to repeat or argue them.